# Spring Data MongoDB repository method delete by list of id

Tags: spring, mongodb, spring-data-mongodb

I have the following document:

```
@Document(collection = "decision_analysis")
public class DecisionAnalysis implements Serializable {

    @Id
    private String id;

...

}
```

I need to delete multiple MongoDB documents via `List<String> decisionAnalysisIds`

How to properly write Spring Data MongoDB repository method in order to do it?

The following doesn't work :

`void deleteByIds(List<String> decisionAnalysisIds);`  - error: No property ids found for type DecisionAnalysis! Did you mean 'id'?

`void deleteById(List<String> decisionAnalysisIds);` - works, but delete only one document

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Use the in clause like this:

```
void deleteByIdIn(List<String> ids);
```

Comment: Perfect, thank you! Also, I have found one more way 'mongoTemplate.remove(new Query(Criteria.where("id").in(decisionAnalysisIds)), DecisionAnalysis.class);'